# get image WIDTH and HEIGHT and write attributes for any image

Tags: jquery

I'm using jScrollPane and I had some issues in Chrome and Safari with the height of the scrollable area.

To make jScrollPane work I have to set HEIGHT and WIDTH for any image inside the scrollable area.

No problem with .css but what if one image is Ex: in portrait mode?
To avoid setting width and height manually I realized... jQuery! :)

For now I have something like this:

```
imageWidth = $('.scroll_pane img').width();
imageHeight = $('.scroll_pane img').height();   
$('.scroll_pane img').css({'width': imageWidth, 'height': imageHeight});
```

That is half correct (I suppose) as now from:

```
<img src="some/url/image.jpg"/>
```

on DOM ready I get this:

```
<img src="some/url/image.jpg" style="width: 120px; height: 220px"/>
```

For the first image. The problem is that now all the other images have the same styles.

How to make EACH image write to it self his own styles?

**EDIT:**

**Solution, thx to Cybernate (and Capsule for future suggestions.):**

```
$(window).load(function () { 
    $('.scroll_pane').jScrollPane();

    $('.scroll_pane img').each(function(){    
        var $this = $(this);   
        var imageWidth = $this.width();   
        var imageHeight = $this.height();        
        $this.css({'width': imageWidth, 'height': imageHeight}); 
    }); 
});
```

Now calculates correctly the images styles and finally jScrollPane works in Safari and Opera!

Comment: To make it even more robust, you should calculate the width/height before calling jScrollPane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the each function and then operate on individual element.
e.g:

```
$('.scroll_pane img').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var imageWidth = $this.width(); 
    var imageHeight = $this.height();    
    $this.css({'width': imageWidth, 'height': imageHeight}); 
});
```

Comment: This is perfectly valid but totally useless in this case: you are trying to solve a problem linked to the fact the size of the images is unknown at the moment you are trying to solve it ;-) If the images were already loaded, you wouldn't have to manually assign their dimensions, jScrollPane would figure them out automatically.

Comment: @Capsule --> Well the answer is working... Theoretically. But not in Chrome and Safari. Styles are now set but as Capsule said...'(read)'. Is there a possibility to use some Images preload? - And NO! Safari and Chrome can't handle well jScrollPane: The scroll stuck in a middle of 'scrolling' due to unknown images styles!!! (Height, and STRANGE: width!)

Comment: If you use $(window).load() as stated in your other comment, yes, it will work but it could imply annoying delays before the jScrollPane is applied (it has to wait for all the images to be loaded). That's why I'm saying this is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: @Capsule --> Well, is the only answer: 'IMPOSSIBLE!' 'cause jScrollpane can't handle images of different sizes in Chrome and Opera? :( ...without setting interval ?

Answer (score 1):

It won't solve your problem because width() and height() is calculated when the event is fired. If images are not loaded, you're screwed (width and height 0, or some pixels in IE).

You probably want to use this method:
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html#autoReinitialise

Comment: thanks for your fast interest on this question. I re-edited my problem a bit... Well even using `$(window).load(function(){` and `imageWidth = $('.scroll_pane img').attr("width");` I get same results! ... some ideas? (even using: `var img = new Image(); ` would be not good?

Comment: Did you try the autoReinitialise option of jScrollPane? I had pretty good results with it.

Comment: @ Capsule I will play around some day with autoReinitialise. For now I got it work with `$(window).load(function() {` but both for the jScrollPane 'call' `$('.scroll_pane').jScrollPane();` and the @Cybernate answer! (I re-edited with the solution) +1 for great suggestions!